# Javascript: Unable to hide entire html row (div tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide an entire html row, which is a div tag, via javascript.  However, I've been unable to do so, so far.  The id I'm trying to hide on is the "row", which is located in the parent div.  I'd like to hide everything contained within this div & all child div's (probably not using the right terminology)

Here's my html.  As you'll see, the "row" value is contained within the parent div.  "TherapistsName" is the name of the textarea:

```
var therapistsName = container.find(".TherapistsName");
var row = therapistsName.parents(".row").first();
row.hide();
```

And here's the html that I want to hide:

```
<div class="row mr-display-row row-eq-height work-task-question-container question-row" style="display: flex;" data-node-name="TherapistsName-7" data-persist="true">
     <div class="col-4 mr-display-title">
         <span class="displayValue">Therapists Name:</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-8">
        <div class="question-item" style="display: table-cell; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
             <div class="input-text-length-container">
                  <textarea name="TherapistsName-7" class="main-input TherapistsName input-text-length auto-size" cols="85" data-allow-persist-answer="True" data-developer-name="TherapistsName" data-disable-on-hide="False" data-hidden="False" data-identifier="" data-node-name="TherapistsName-7" data-parent-branch-name="SpokeWithTherapist-Yes" data-previous-value="" data-question-group-name="" data-question-id="175" data-question-messages="[]" data-read-only="False" data-reset-answer-on-hide="True" data-tree-level="3" data-type="string" data-value-orig="" data-value-type="TextArea" id="TherapistsName-7" maxchars="1000" onchange="assignedWorkTasks.QuestionChange(this);;assignedWorkTasks.QuestionChangeComplete(this);" rows="1" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 26px;"></textarea><br>
                       <span class="chars-remaining" style="width:100%;float:left;margin:0 0 0 0;font-size:10px;">1000 characters remaining
                       </span>
             </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why this would hide the entire div tag??
Thanks

Comment: what is `container`? If you want to hide the children of `.row` you can use `row.children().hide()`.

Comment: I think more code or more details is needed. I don't see any `id` named `row`. I can see `row` is a `class`. Also when you want to hide this div ?

Comment: just get id from html and apply style in that

Comment: You might want to use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of parents. Either way your code is doing hiding the row, which is what you want from your description.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a css class which contains `display:none;` and then add this class to the parent classlist using js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this problem.

```
$("body").find(".TherapistsName").find(".row").first().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`row.hide();` You are saying hide this element. Its is doing what you asked. Hide the first parent element you find with the selector `.row` .

Since you are using jQuery there is a few answer's that can be used here.

Here is a quick example from jQuerys site =>

```
var spans = $( "span" );
$( "p" ).find( spans ).css( "color", "red" );
```

Don't forget you can use jQuerys dollar sign shorthand `$("someElement")` to quickly select the DOM element you want.

Doc reference: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

First add the id as row then add
**$('#row').addClass("displaynone");** 
by adding displaynone you can definitely hide

```
    <div class="row mr-display-row row-eq-height work-task-question-container question-row" id='row' style="display: flex;" data-node-name="TherapistsName-7" data-persist="true">
     <div class="col-4 mr-display-title">
         <span class="displayValue">Therapists Name:</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-8">
        <div class="question-item" style="display: table-cell; word-break: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
             <div class="input-text-length-container">
                  <textarea name="TherapistsName-7" class="main-input TherapistsName input-text-length auto-size" cols="85" data-allow-persist-answer="True" data-developer-name="TherapistsName" data-disable-on-hide="False" data-hidden="False" data-identifier="" data-node-name="TherapistsName-7" data-parent-branch-name="SpokeWithTherapist-Yes" data-previous-value="" data-question-group-name="" data-question-id="175" data-question-messages="[]" data-read-only="False" data-reset-answer-on-hide="True" data-tree-level="3" data-type="string" data-value-orig="" data-value-type="TextArea" id="TherapistsName-7" maxchars="1000" onchange="assignedWorkTasks.QuestionChange(this);;assignedWorkTasks.QuestionChangeComplete(this);" rows="1" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 26px;"></textarea><br>
                       <span class="chars-remaining" style="width:100%;float:left;margin:0 0 0 0;font-size:10px;">1000 characters remaining
                       </span>
             </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var therapistsName = container.find(".TherapistsName");
var row = therapistsName.parents(".row").first();
$('#row').addClass("displaynone");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does hide the entire row,

[demo hide row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjQmR.gif)

But as mentioned, if you're able to add an ID and avoid the traversing w/ jQuery, you'd be simplifying it significantly.